# How to terminate AsyncTask?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Please don't think it's a redundant question. Please read completely.

I have an infinite loop inside the doInBackground(Void... params) of AsyncTask. And there's a callback function within doInBackground(). So, I am not able to terminate this task using cancel(), onCancelled() and isCancelled() approach. The problem is the execution waits at the callback function forever. So, no matter where (within doInBackground) I write this isCancelled() check to break out of the infinite loop, it doesnt get executed.

Does anyone have a solution for this kind of problem? Or anyone had a requirement similar to this?

```
@Override
protected void onCancelled()
{
    // Socket Close
}

@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        try
        {
            // Socket Open

            while (true)
            {

                socket.receive();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "callback function"?  A callback is an interface, not a function. Is that socket.receive? I guess it is as it's the only thing in there.   What does your socket.receive look like?  Sorry, but I've read your question several times and can't understand exactly what you are asking.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Hi Simon, socket.receive() is nothing but DatagramSocket's receive method (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#receive(java.net.DatagramPacket). This thread actually listens to any incoming UDP packets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you start with any receiving operations, call `socket.setSoTimeout(int timeout)` and give it a timeout according to your needs (If you usually wait a little time for data, you can use 1000ms or less. If it might take long to receive data, use a greater value, 10000ms for example).

Then, in your loop, after `socket.receive` method, check if the task was cancelled (`isCancelled() == true`) and if it was, break out from the loop.

Comment: Hi Jong, thanks. I think this will solve my problem. I will try this first thing tomorrow morning.

Comment: @Jong : I receive a packet once per minute, and my fear is that i can loose a packet between the socket timeout and the new socket.receive command. Is this possible? Because it is obvious that i can not set a timeout of one minute. The reason is that I need to get the socket closed within 4 seconds from the termination of asynctask.

Comment: @Gaucho Fear not, you can't lose anything this way. But I don't think that's what you need - `setSoTimeout` only applies on read timeout (timeout when calling read on the socket). It wont cause the socket to get closed after that timeout...

Answer (score 1):

You should use a timeout in your `socket.receive()`, so from time to time it passes control back to `AsyncTask`, where you may check `isCancelled()` and terminate the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
        @Override
    protected void onCancelled()
    {
        // Socket Close
    }

    @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            try
            {
                // Socket Open

                while (!isCancelled())
                {

                    socket.receive();
                    OnProgressUpdate(...);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
            return null;
        }
    @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(...) {
                receiveing=true;
            }

boolean receiveing;
```

Since I don't know what you are trying to achieve, and the question wasn't clear, I am not sure if this is what you are asking. You would put the cancel() where you need it. 

 And infinite loop is not a good idea...

Comment: Hi wtsang02, yes I know infinite loop is a bad idea. But, for a UDP  listener, what else I could do.. and suggestion? And in your solution, while(!iscancelled()) will not be called unless some packet has been received by the socket. isn't it?